# Reading LDAP attribute works, modifying it results in "attribute type undefined"

Tags: ldap, citrix, novell

I have a Citrix ADC and want to setup multi-factor authentication using an OTP token. Since I do not have an AD but an LDAP directory only, the Authentication LDAP Server is set to NDS.

The Citrix ADC read from and writes into the field `userParameters` to store the OTP information. When I try to add an OTP device, the LDAP query fails with `userParameters: attribute type undefined`. The attribute itself is present and for testing purposes, I used my bind user to manually write the required OTP value into this field using Apache Directory Studio. This worked, the attribute is present and the bind user is able to write into this field. When I try to read it, i.e. the OTP token is challenged, it is read successfully and I can perform a successful OTP authentication. However, if I try to modify the value, e.g. if I try to delete a device or register a new device, I get the mentioned error message.

In the slapd logs, I can see the following:

```
Feb 29 14:40:52 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 fd=48 ACCEPT from IP=172.30.30.100:17045 (IP=0.0.0.0:636)
Feb 29 14:40:52 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 fd=48 TLS established tls_ssf=256 ssf=256
Feb 29 14:40:52 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 op=0 BIND dn="cn=adc_binduser,ou=accounts,o=myorg" method=128
Feb 29 14:40:52 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 op=0 BIND dn="cn=adc_binduser,ou=accounts,o=myorg" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
Feb 29 14:40:52 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Feb 29 14:40:52 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 op=1 SRCH base="o=myorg" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(?SAMACCOUNTNAME=otptestuser)(objectClass=*))"
Feb 29 14:40:52 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 op=1 SRCH attr=PwdLastSet UserAccountControl msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed maxPwdAge objectClass userParameters mail
Feb 29 14:40:53 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Feb 29 14:40:53 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 op=2 MOD dn="cn=otptestuser,ou=testusers,ou=accounts,o=myorg"
Feb 29 14:40:53 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 op=2 MOD attr=userParameters
Feb 29 14:40:53 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 op=2 RESULT tag=103 err=17 text=userParameters: attribute type undefined
Feb 29 14:40:53 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 op=3 UNBIND
Feb 29 14:40:53 ldap1srv slapd[24460]: conn=89868 fd=48 closed
```

(I redacted/modified the actual DN and bind-user for security purposes)

In the `aaad.debug` log of the ADC which connects to the LDAP server, I can see the same error as it is propagated back to the ADC:

```
Thu Feb 29 12:51:09 2024
 /usr/home/build/adc/usr.src/netscaler/aaad/ldap_common.c[2094]: ns_ldap_register_otp 0-562: Attempting to modify attribute 'userParameters'
Thu Feb 29 12:51:09 2024
 /usr/home/build/adc/usr.src/netscaler/aaad/ldap_drv.c[2622]: get_otp_attribute 0-562: OTP Secret Attribute name: <userParameters>, length 15
Thu Feb 29 12:51:09 2024
 /usr/home/build/adc/usr.src/netscaler/aaad/naaad.c[6410]: register_timer 0-562: setting timer 1984852
Thu Feb 29 12:51:09 2024
 /usr/home/build/adc/usr.src/netscaler/aaad/ldap_common.c[448]: ns_ldap_check_result 0-562: checking LDAP result.  Expecting 103 (LDAP_RES_MODIFY)
Thu Feb 29 12:51:09 2024
 /usr/home/build/adc/usr.src/netscaler/aaad/ldap_common.c[486]: ns_ldap_check_result 0-562: ldap_result found expected result LDAP_RES_MODIFY
Thu Feb 29 12:51:09 2024
 /usr/home/build/adc/usr.src/netscaler/aaad/ldap_common.c[310]: ns_show_ldap_err_string 0-562: LDAP error string: <<userParameters: attribute type undefined>>
Thu Feb 29 12:51:09 2024
/usr/home/build/adc/usr.src/netscaler/aaad/ldap_common.c[496]: ns_ldap_check_result 0-562: LDAP action failed (error 17): Undefined attribute type
Thu Feb 29 12:51:09 2024
 /usr/home/build/adc/usr.src/netscaler/aaad/ldap_common.c[498]: ns_ldap_check_result 0-562: For user otptestuser, LDAP authentication failed (error 17): Undefined attribute type
Thu Feb 29 12:51:09 2024
 /usr/home/build/adc/usr.src/netscaler/aaad/naaad.c[6487]: unregister_timer 0-562: releasing timer 1984852
Thu Feb 29 12:51:09 2024
 /usr/home/build/adc/usr.src/netscaler/aaad/ldap_drv.c[3863]: receive_ldap_register_otp_event 0-562: In receive_ldap_register_otp_event: Unexpected result -1 in the attempt to modify password for user otptestuser
```

(Please ignore the different timestamps as they are from two different testings. The LDAP and ADC are time synchronized and the errors are always the same)

The otptestuser consists of the following objectClasses: `inetOrgPerson`, `ndsLoginProperties`, `organizationalPerson`, `Person`, `posixAccount`, `pwmUser`, `Top`, and `uamPosixUser`.

I suspect the error on the LDAP server and not on the ADC. From the samaccountname, the correct DN of the OTP test user was found by the LDAP server. Hence, looking up the user works. However, I do not understand why I get the error message that the attribute type is undefined when it is modified, but it works if it is read. What is my mistake here?

Comment: Are the userParameters and sAMAccountName attributes in your LDAP schema currently?

Comment: @u1686_grawity yes, I checked it today and both properties are in the LDAP schema.

Comment: From the plural form of the attribute name "userParameters", it seems to be a compound attribute. Could it be that the value provided is wrong type (primitive type provided but compound type expected). When you changed it manually, whatever UI makes an implicit convert of your input to compound value.